# Spark: object not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I have a batch job which I am try to convert to structured streaming. I am getting the following error:

```
20/03/31 15:09:23 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.apple.ireporter.analytics.compute.AggregateKey
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.apple.ireporter.analytics.compute.AggregateKey, value: d_)
```

... where "d_" is the last row in the dataset

This is the relevant code snippet

```
    df.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
      import spark.implicits._
      val javaRdd = batchDF.toJavaRDD
      val dataframeToRowColFunction = new RowToColumn(table)
      println("Back to Main class")
      val combinedRdd =javaRdd.flatMapToPair(dataframeToRowColFunction.FlatMapData2).combineByKey(aggrCreateComb.createCombiner,aggrMerge.aggrMerge,aggrMergeCombiner.aggrMergeCombiner)
      // spark.createDataFrame( combinedRdd).show(1); // I commented this
      // combinedRdd.collect() // I added this as a test
    }
```

This is the FlatMapData2 class

```
  val FlatMapData2: PairFlatMapFunction[Row, AggregateKey, AggregateValue] = new PairFlatMapFunction[Row, AggregateKey, AggregateValue]() {
    //val FlatMapData: PairFlatMapFunction[Row, String, AggregateValue] = new PairFlatMapFunction[Row, String, AggregateValue]() {
    override def call(x: Row) = {
      val tuples = new util.ArrayList[Tuple2[AggregateKey, AggregateValue]]
      val decomposedEvents = decomposer.decomposeDistributed(x)
      decomposedEvents.foreach {
        y =>  tuples.add(Tuple2(y._1,y._2))
      }
      tuples.iterator()
    }
  }
```

Here is the aggregate Key class

```
class AggregateKey(var partitionkeys: Map[Int,Any],var clusteringkeys : Map[Int,Any]) extends Comparable [AggregateKey]{
...
}
```

I am new to this and any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if anything else needs to be added

Comment: The initial error was due to ```spark.createDataFrame( combinedRdd).show(1);```. I replaced that by ```combinedRdd.collect()``` and now it is throwing **NotSerializableException**. I have modified the question accordingly

Comment: Probably, that's because of `Map[Int,Any]` Any is allways the problem, avoid it at all costs everywhere. Scala has a potent type system for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by making the AggregateKey extend java.io.Serializable

```
class AggregateKey(var partitionkeys: Map[Int,Any],var clusteringkeys : Map[Int,Any]) extends java.io.Serializable{
```